# Ember-simple-auth and ember-fetch no authorization in fetch query

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am using ember with ember-simple-auth(1.7.0) for authentication. Here is the application adapter function :

```
authorize(xhr) {
    let { email, token } = this.get('session.data.authenticated');
    let authData = `Token token="${token}", email="${email}"`;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authData);
  }
```

When I use ember-fetch(5.1.3) there is no header for authentication :

```
fetch('/appname/v1/user/count'+count_params).then((response)=>{return response.json()})
```

The same model do successful emberDS query with the auth info in the header.
How can I add the information to the fetch headers ?

EDIT :

This is the service I created to wrap fetch :

```
import Service from '@ember/service';
import fetch from 'fetch';
import { inject as service} from "@ember/service"

export default Service.extend({
  fetch(url){
    let { email, token } = this.get('session.data.authenticated')
    let authData = `Token token="${token}", email="${email}"`
    return fetch(url,{headers: {'Authorization': authData}}).then(
      (response)=>{return response.json()}
    )
  },
  session: service()
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create fetch wrapper service and use it, instead of "raw" fetch and boilerplating.

Raw usage possible with headers - https://github.com/github/fetch#post-json

Comment: The header doc was very helpful